# How to split text to columns by periods in SQL?

Tags: sql, csv

I have a column that returns data in this format below. I'm trying to write a query so it only returns the fruit name (ie. apple, pear, peach).

```
text.apple.food.day1_2018.store
text.pear.food.day23_2018.store
text.peach.food.day4_2018.store
text.apple.food.day15_2018.store
```

Is this possible? Can I do a text to columns sort of function and then only pull the fruit names? Thanks!

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add the tag for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `db2`, `sql-server`, ...

Comment: What have you tried yourself? What goes wrong? Please show us your own research.

Comment: First, the obligatory mention that this violates 1st normal form of database normalization and suggest you fix that so you won't have to jump through hoops like this in the first place. Second, will the element of this delimited list that you are after always be the second one?  Can it be NULL?

Answer (score 2):

You can go about this in a couple of ways.  I'd suggest using String functions in whatever SQL language you are using in order to get the position of the First "." character, and the Second "." character and using those in a Substring to pull back that middle part. In T-SQL (MSSQL) it'd look something like this.

```
Declare @TextTable Table 
( TxtColumn VarChar(50))
Insert Into @TextTable 
Values
('text.apple.food.day1_2018.store'),
('text.pear.food.day23_2018.store'),
('text.peach.food.day4_2018.store'),
('text.apple.food.day15_2018.store')



Select SUBSTRING(t.TxtColumn, CHARINDEX('.',t.TxtColumn)+1, CharIndex('.',t.txtColumn,CHARINDEX('.',t.TxtColumn)+1) - (CHARINDEX('.',t.TxtColumn)+1))
From @TextTable t
```

Answer (score 1):

In Oracle, I'd use a regular expression to get the second element in the string. Specifically, it returns the 2nd instance on a line of a set of any characters that are followed by a literal period. This example uses whats called a CTE (Common Table Expression, or the WITH clause) to set up what is logically a temp table with the data set.  In reality you'd start with the bottom SELECT, substituting your table for `tbl` and your column for `str`. ALWAYS put values in your test dataset that will test every condition.  Always expect the unexpected! NULLs, spaces, values with specials characters, etc. Especially if the data comes from a user at a keyboard.

You should be able to apply this logic to whatever RDBMS you are using.  Good luck!

```
with tbl(str) as (
  select 'text.apple.food.day1_2018.store' from dual union all
  select 'text.pear.food.day23_2018.store' from dual union all
  select 'text.peach.food.day4_2018.store' from dual union all
  select 'text..food.day15_2018.store' from dual union all
  select '.banana.food.day15_2018.store' from dual union all
  select 'text.apple.food.day15_2018.store' from dual 
)
select regexp_substr(str, '(.*?)(\.)', 1, 2, NULL, 1)
from tbl;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a modern database such a Postgres, the `split_part` [function](https://w3resource.com/PostgreSQL/split_part-function.php) may be available. If so, you could try:

```
with your_values as
(
    select 'text.apple.food.day1_2018.store' as value
)
select
    split_part(value, '.', 2) as fruit
from
    your_values
```

Result:

```
apple
```